# How to fetch data from multiple table using eloquent in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to build query like this in laravel 5.3

```
SELECT p.post_text, p.bbcode_uid, u.username, t.forum_id, t.topic_title, t.topic_time, t.topic_id, t.topic_poster
FROM phpbb_topics t, phpbb_posts p, phpbb_users u
WHERE t.forum_id = 9
AND p.post_id = t.topic_first_post_id
AND u.user_id = t.topic_poster
ORDER BY t.topic_time
DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider for example there are two tables one is **users** and the other is **posts**

while creating migration add user_id foreign key to your posts table as

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

create **User** and **Post** model, and in your **User** model define relationship to **Post** as

```
public function post(){
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

and in your **Post** model define a relationship to **User** model as

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

now you can get the user from Post model

```
$post = Post::findOrFail(1);
return $post->user;
```

Comment: I don't wanna use foreign key. without that how can i implement it?

Comment: If don't want to use foreign key then it's not possible you either execute the raw query or use eloquent join methods. But using foreign key has many advantages.